# Set value of cells based on the value of a cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with a set of tables acting as a "database":
http://prntscr.com/dbbkyv

A table with a number of persons having combinations of items in said database:
http://prntscr.com/dbblhy

And finally a table summing the statistics of the different items:
http://prntscr.com/dbblwe

Color code is as follows: http://prntscr.com/dbbm8w

Green cells are a dropdown list.

How could I have the sum of each stats for each person in table 3?

In this example, Person 1 should have `36` in "Stam" column, `34` in "Int" and `61` in "Spell".

Here is [the Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VsXAsvYHNvMY7g_qf70P3eiuz-pboN-pa5TdNwN7uXY/edit?usp=sharing) used in the example.

Comment: He has Helmet 1 and Torso 2, it equals to 36. I'm an idiot, editing right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try, in B21, C21 and D21 in order:

```
=vlookup(vlookup($A21;$A$13:$C$16;column();0);$A$4:$D$6;column();0)+vlookup(vlookup($A21;$A$13:$C$16;column()+1;0);$F$4:$I$6;column();0)  

=vlookup(vlookup($a21;$a$13:$c$16;column()-1;0);$a$4:$d$6;column();0)+vlookup(vlookup($a21;$a$13:$c$16;column();0);$f$4:$i$6;column();0)  

=vlookup(vlookup($a21;$a$13:$c$16;column()-2;0);$a$4:$d$6;column();0)+vlookup(vlookup($a21;$a$13:$c$16;column()-1;0);$f$4:$i$6;column();0
```

This is complexity purely resulting from the layout you chose.